# How to check if a column has not null constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table in which I have a column that have a not null constraint.

Now, what if I want to check if column has not null constraint defined or not for specific column?

Is there any query to find out it?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I have tried a lot but found nothing helpful. Is it too tough using SQL Server? Any DB experts??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

This query will show all columns from all tables and a whole host of information on them. The column you would want is: `IS_NULLABLE` that can have the value 'YES' or 'NO'

[COLUMNS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 6):

Something like

```
SELECT o.name AS tab, c.name AS col, c.is_nullable 
FROM sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.name like '%yourtable%' and type = 'U'
```

See [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) and [sys.objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

there is a table sys.all_columns
and a column in this table called is_nullable

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177522(v=sql.105).aspx

```
select s.name, c.name, c.is_nullable from sys.tables s, sys.all_columns c
where s.object_id = c.object_id
and s.type = 'U' -- USER_TABLE
and  c.is_nullable = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There's some catalog views you can use:

```
// information about check constraints
select * from sys.check_constraints 

// information about specific columns
select name, is_nullable from sys.columns

// information about tables
select * from sys.tables
```

The `sys.columns is_nullable`field holds information about nullability.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple command that will list -  *Field, Type, Null, Key, Default*

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM Your_Table_Name;
```